# MySQL query on product attibute table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table which include product and attribute relations,

```
id  productid attributeid arributevalueid
18  521       12           36
17  521       11           43
16  521       9            16
29  522       18           168
28  522       17           138
27  522       16           115
26  522       15           71
25  522       12           36
24  522       11           48
23  522       9            19
```

i got a problem when i write a sql query, i'm trying to to filter product which has all attributes,

ex - **if i pass attribute value 16 and 36 the product matched is 521**

i test a mysql query below

```
$nweryt=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM 
tbl_proattrconnect 
WHERE 
tbl_proattrconnect.attroid=9 AND tbl_proattrconnect.attrvalid=16 
AND tbl_proattrconnect.attroid=12 AND tbl_proattrconnect.attrvalid=36');

echo mysql_num_rows($nweryt);
```

But this cant get the results and show 0, can anyone help me please, thanks a lot

Comment: I do not understand your example: with 16 and 36 you won't get any row at all

Comment: in your sample data there is no data that has both "id:9;value:16" and "id:12;value:36" so having 0 row count is correct. What is the problem?

Comment: hi the attribute values matched 16 and 36 both have only on product no 521 i need to get that results

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: It's totaly clear, what he's asking. Have a look at the arributevalueid column, there's id 16 and 36 for product 521.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a try with this:

```
SELECT
productid
FROM
tbl_proattrconnect
GROUP BY productid
HAVING SUM(attributevalueid IN (16, 36)) >= 2 /*here you specify after the >= how many attributes you have in IN()*/
AND SUM(attributevalueid BETWEEN x and y) >= 1 /*here you just always leave it at >= 1*/
AND SUM(attributevalueid BETWEEN z and w) >= 1 /*feel free to add as much checks as necessary.*/
```

This uses a little trick. `attributevalueid IN (16, 36)` returns true or false, 1 or 0.

Alternatively you can self join the table, but this may have a bit worse performance and can be quite clumsy if you have to check for more attributes. You have to self join the table once for each attribute.

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b16e7f/2/0)

Comment: 1. Again overkill. Tell me what this can accomplish that attributevalueid=16 and attributevalueid=36 cant.

Comment: Maybe you just haven't understood the question? Read it again!

Comment: hi for this if i pass 16 and 36 i wanna get 521 as results

Comment: Yes, that works. Click on the link I provided in my answer and you can even see it live :)

Comment: thanks for answer so should i only need to change (16, 36)) >= 2 for additional attribute values also i have to get results using between is this support for between

Comment: If you have to check for example for 43 too, you change it to `(16, 36, 43)) >= 3;` Please explain in more detail your `between` requirement. Best would be you edit your question.

Comment: its great, is that will support AND (tbl_attrvalues.attrval BETWEEN $mnv AND $mxv) kind of query part becoz some attrubute values have check for range, thanks

Comment: @smithbandara Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @fancyPants i just got a problem with this,i appreciate you can help me  if i write this kind of query 
SELECT proid FROM tbl_proattrconnect GROUP BY proid HAVING SUM(attrvalid IN (16,168)) >=2 ,the 16 and 168 are the values of same attribute,that values have on 2 products, so it need to return both 521 and 522 products as results, thanks again

Comment: My query is for products that have both those attributes. If you want to have all products that have either the one or the other, you just `or` them. Just do `SELECT proid FROM tbl_proattrconnect WHERE attrvalid IN (16, 168);` The `IN()` is just short for `(attrvalid = 16 OR attrvalid = 168)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table to itself to make this happen.  For example:

```
SELECT t1.productid
FROM tbl_proattrconnect t1
JOIN tbl_proattrconnect t2 ON t1.productid = t2.productid
WHERE
  (t1.attroid = 9 AND t1.attrvalid = 16)
AND
  (t2.attroid = 12 AND t2.attrvalid = 36)
```

Comment: although this will do the job but why? you can just use OR if its the same table O.o

Comment: Using OR will give you too many results.  He just wants the single product ID that matches both sets of attribute/value pairs.  They are not equivalent.  Returning 522 is incorrect.

Comment: seems working fine this solution, if i wanna pass 3 or 4 attribute values should i change the join

Comment: Then you have to join the same table multiple times. As I said in my answer.

Comment: ops is there any short way becoz i have around 10 attributes and those are dynamicly pass by layered navigation form :)

Comment: Well, I'm wondering what's unclear about my solution? Feel free to ask :)

Comment: @fancyPants  the answer is correct but i have to use BETWEEN ex AND (tbl_attrvalues.attrval BETWEEN $mnv AND $mxv) is that support

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to use OR rather than AND? Try again, this will display 521 and 522

```
$nweryt=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM 
tbl_proattrconnect 
WHERE 
tbl_proattrconnect.attroid=9 AND tbl_proattrconnect.attrvalid=16 
OR tbl_proattrconnect.attroid=12 AND tbl_proattrconnect.attrvalid=36
order by productid'
);
```

Comment: i used or but it retuns lots of results i only need to get 521 if if pass attribute value 16 and 36

Comment: @smithbandara He hasn't understood the question, but downvoted mine. I got correct answer, have a try :)

Comment: @fancyPants no its both of you who dont understand. You say your passing value 16 and 36 but in your query your also getting 12 and 36 which is not a value of 521. e.g. getting the 0 rows.

Comment: Who said anything about 12? It was a try of the OP to get the result. The task is "if i pass attribute value 16 and 36 the product matched is 521".

Comment: Look at his sample query. This is the reason he is asking the question cause his query results to 0. Sometimes OP does not know how to ask a question so you should have the initiative to understand it for them. Yes your query works but this is not the issue.

Comment: @fancyPants by the way i did not downvote your answer but just tried to explain why you might have gotten it

Comment: Okay, sorry I downvoted you, but I can't take it back, cause your answer is still wrong. FYI, when you delete it, you get your reputation back. That's why one actually shouldn't take it offensively, it's a feature of this site meant to help keeping the site clean.

Comment: Its okay i was running my mouth about you not understanding it but it seems i was the one who didnt. Face palm. I based my answer from his sample query rather than the actual question. Anyway bottom line is we want to help other members and im glad you assisted him. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your query because you are using an AND operator and not OR.
Remember:

- The **AND** operator displays a record if both the first condition AND the second condition are true.
- The **OR** operator displays a record if either the first condition OR the second condition is true.

Read this info http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

```
$nweryt=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tbl_proattrconnect 
                     WHERE 
                       tbl_proattrconnect.attroid=9 AND tbl_proattrconnect.attrvalid=16 
                     OR 
                       tbl_proattrconnect.attroid=12 AND tbl_proattrconnect.attrvalid=36');

echo mysql_num_rows($nweryt);
```

Also can write the same query but shorter:

```
SELECT * FROM 
tbl_proattrconnect 
WHERE 
    tbl_proattrconnect.attroid IN(9,12) AND tbl_proattrconnect.attrvalid IN(16,36);
```

Comment: soryy i only need to get 521 for the answer, as you can see arributevalueid 16 and 36 only have on product id 521 :)